# Python regular expression for multiple tags

Tags: python, html, regex

I would like to know how to retrieve all results from each `<p>` tag.

```
import re
htmlText = '<p data="5" size="4">item1</p><p size="4">item2</p><p size="4">item3</p>'
print re.match('<p[^>]*size="[0-9]">(.*?)</p>', htmlText).groups()
```

result:

```
('item1', )
```

what I need:

```
('item1', 'item2', 'item3')
```

Comment: -1 for trying to parse non-regular languages with regular expressions.

Comment: agreed, isn't there a python library, that's famous for parsing html? BeautifulSoup? htmllib?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I needed a python way to print out all the values of the p tags from a small html without installing anything new in the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex answer is extremely fragile. Here's proof (and a working BeautifulSoup example).

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

# Here's your HTML
html = '<p data="5" size="4">item1</p><p size="4">item2</p><p size="4">item3</p>'

# Here's some simple HTML that breaks your accepted 
# answer, but doesn't break BeautifulSoup.
# For each example, the regex will ignore the first <p> tag.
html2 = '<p size="4" data="5">item1</p><p size="4">item2</p><p size="4">item3</p>'
html3 = '<p data="5" size="4" >item1</p><p size="4">item2</p><p size="4">item3</p>'
html4 = '<p data="5" size="12">item1</p><p size="4">item2</p><p size="4">item3</p>'

# This BeautifulSoup code works for all the examples.
paragraphs = BeautifulSoup(html).findAll('p')
items = [''.join(p.findAll(text=True)) for p in paragraphs]
```

Use BeautifulSoup.

Comment: I don't think you need to import re.  Also, I'm curious what your example provides that mine doesn't other than the list comprehension.

Comment: Brett - mine will correctly handle cases like <p><b>item1</b></p>, whereas yours will fail. 

Also, the items array here will convert to a list of strings, whereas your example will return tag.contents, which is actually a (very memory hungry) BeautifulSoup object.

Comment: Cool!  I didn't know about the object being memory intensive, I've only used it on small parsing projects and never run into issues.  Thanks for the update.  I voted yours up based on your explanation.

Comment: I've used BeautifulSoup for some very large (500KB+) HTML files, and you run into a pretty hard wall if you don't learn to conserve memory. BeautifulSoup is extremely convenient but NOT very efficient.

Answer (score 11):

For this type of problem, it is recommended to use a DOM parser, not regex.

I've seen [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) frequently recommended for Python

Answer (score 5):

Beautiful soup is definitely the way to go with a problem like this.  The code is cleaner and easier to read.  Once you have it installed, getting all the tags looks something like this.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

def getTags(tag):
  f = urllib2.urlopen("http://cnn.com")
  soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read())
  return soup.findAll(tag)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  tags = getTags('p')
  for tag in tags: print(tag.contents)
```

This will print out all the values of the p tags.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just needed a python way to print out all the values of the p tags without installing anything new in the server.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.findall` like this:

```
import re
html = '<p data="5" size="4">item1</p><p size="4">item2</p><p size="4">item3</p>'
print re.findall('<p[^>]*size="[0-9]">(.*?)</p>', html)
# This prints: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
```

**Edit**: ...but as the many commenters have pointed out, using regular expressions to parse HTML is usually a bad idea.

Comment: Thanks! I just found it on Python docs! http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/regex.html

Comment: I'm sorry but this is an awful answer.  What if there's a space between the size attribute and the closing bracket: <p size="0" >?

Comment: @Triptych: There isn't.  Have you considered the possibility that the OP knows what he's doing? 8-)  Had the question been "How do I parse this HTML?" then I wouldn't have suggested a regular expression.  But it was "How do I make my regular expression work?", and this is an answer to that question.

Comment: -1: gave an example of regex to parse html, without even saying that this is really bad, and lots of newbies will read. Evil comes from acts like that.

Comment: @RichieHindle: The original poster didn't say anything about making a regular expression work.  He said he wanted to retrieve the results from each p tag.  Regular expressions aren't suited to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, [xml.dom.minidom](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) will parse your HTML if,

- ...it is wellformed
- ...you embed it in a single root element.

E.g.,

```
>>> import xml.dom.minidom
>>> htmlText = '<p data="5" size="4">item1</p><p size="4">item2</p><p size="4">item3</p>'
>>> d = xml.dom.minidom.parseString('<not_p>%s</not_p>' % htmlText)
>>> tuple(map(lambda e: e.firstChild.wholeText, d.firstChild.childNodes))
('item1', 'item2', 'item3')
```